# Getting Backup Photos with getContentResolver().query

Tags: android, mediastore

I am trying to get my backup photos with

```
mediaCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri("content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider"), projection, selection, selectionArgs, "");
```

but I get no result. What is the correct Uri? Or do I have to use another api?

I tried also

```
Uri ImageUri = Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/images/media");
            mediaCursor = getContentResolver().query(ImageUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, "");
```

but I get this error message:

Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.gallery3d.provider.GalleryProvider from ProcessRecord{41d647c8 23247:org.de.jmg.jmgphotouploader/u0a198} (pid=23247, uid=10198) requires com.google.android.gallery3d.permission.GALLERY_PROVIDER or com.google.android.gallery3d.permission.GALLERY_PROVIDER

Comment: So your backed up photos are on your pc? Or where?

Comment: No! In Google Drive (or another cloud service).

Comment: one workaround is to include google photos in google drive....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround with Google Drive Api:

```
Drive.Files.List request = client.files().list()
                                        .setPageSize(100)
                                        .setFields("files,kind,nextPageToken")
                                        .setQ(null)
                                        .setSpaces("photos");
```

The problem is that albums are not shown.
Another possibility is https://roostertech.wordpress.com/2013/08/09/accessing-gphoto-android/, but the api used is a bit outdated.